# ActionItem lost on screen rotation

Tags: android, fragment, actionbarsherlock

I use a sherlockfragmentactivity which has a ViewPager, two Fragment and an ActionBar displaying two tabs. I populate the actions items from the fragment but i have to call the method

```
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in order than the fragment display the Actionbar MenuItem.
But when the screen oriention change, the MenuItems are not displayed.

Here is my code to create a option menu in my first fragment :

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.add(R.string.action_refresh).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_refresh)
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    refresh();
                    return false;
                }
            }).setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add(R.string.action_add_a_file).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_upload)
            .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add(R.string.action_settings).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences)
            .setIntent(new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), SettingsActivity.class))
            .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

}
```

Is there a way to properly add item to the action bar from a SherlockFragment and how can i keep these item in ActionBar after screen orientation change ?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best solution but since i have a known fixed number of fragment, i instantiate them in the `onCreate` method on my SherlockActivity and call after the instanciation :  `invalidateOptionsMenu();` Then in the `onActivityCreated` method of my fragments, after what i have to do there i call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`. Thus my ActionItems are displayed for each fragment even after screen orientation.

Answer (score 0):

add following line in your FragmentActivity in the manifeast file
`android:configChanges="orientation"`

orientation is automatically handled by the system itself. but i don't know weather it is a efficient way or not.

Comment: using of `android:configChanges="orientation"` is [not recommended](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html#bad-practice-retain-the-activity)